# Why doesn't my array have any elements in it

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup

So I created an array to store data from jsoup calls and when I try to run this method to actually put dynamic data, it simply doesn't put anything in it. It's being freaky freaky.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Book> lstBook;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstBook = new ArrayList<>();
        getWebsite();
        lstBook.add(new Book("Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple", "All you really got to know is that this is THE Greatest Book Ever!", "http://fmcdn.Bookhere.com/store/Book/18607/cover.jpg?token=7ef7d63df101d2e3ff52c9c8e15aa6ae4abc176e&amp;ttl=1594666800&amp;v=1594289853"));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple", "All you really got to know is that this is THE Greatest Book Ever!", "http://fmcdn.Bookhere.com/store/Book/18607/cover.jpg?token=7ef7d63df101d2e3ff52c9c8e15aa6ae4abc176e&amp;ttl=1594666800&amp;v=1594289853"));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple", "All you really got to know is that this is THE Greatest Book Ever!", "http://fmcdn.Bookhere.com/store/Book/18607/cover.jpg?token=7ef7d63df101d2e3ff52c9c8e15aa6ae4abc176e&amp;ttl=1594666800&amp;v=1594289853"));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple", "All you really got to know is that this is THE Greatest Book Ever!", "http://fmcdn.Bookhere.com/store/Book/18607/cover.jpg?token=7ef7d63df101d2e3ff52c9c8e15aa6ae4abc176e&amp;ttl=1594666800&amp;v=1594289853"));
        lstBook.add(new Book("Kenichi: The Mightiest Disciple", "All you really got to know is that this is THE Greatest Book Ever!", "http://fmcdn.Bookhere.com/store/Book/18607/cover.jpg?token=7ef7d63df101d2e3ff52c9c8e15aa6ae4abc176e&amp;ttl=1594666800&amp;v=1594289853"));
```

These static inputs populate the app screen.

```
        RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_id);
        RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, lstBook);
        myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }

    private void getWebsite() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.Bookhere.cc/ranking/").get();
                    Elements description = doc.select("p.Book-list-1-item-title");
                    int length = description.size();
                    String cont = description.eq(1).text();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        String imgUrl = description.eq(i).text();
                        String title = doc.select("img.Book-list-1-cover").eq(i).attr("src");
                        Book test = (new Book(title,"All you really got to know is that this is THE Greatest Book Ever!","http://fmcdn.Bookhere.com/store/Book/18607/cover.jpg?token=7ef7d63df101d2e3ff52c9c8e15aa6ae4abc176e&amp;ttl=1594666800&amp;v=1594289853"));
                        lstBook.add(test);
                        Log.d("Yuh", lstManga.toString());
```

the output for this `[com.example.mangadrip.Manga@f128bbf, com.example.mangadrip.Manga@633e28c]` which is the root of what i think is the problem.

```
                        Log.d("Yuh", test.getTitle());
                    }
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    Log.d("Yuh","This duo");
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And so when I compile the app, I get no inputs as if nothing was ever put in `lstBook`. The only thing it keeps is the manual entry right under the call to the method.

**SOLUTION**

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }});`

Comment: Amazon throws captcha. So in your html there is value for `lstBook`. Easiest solution is to use proxies

Comment: Sorry, but that was the wrong link. The call works, and something is being stored at the end of getWebsite call, but nothing is populating on the app screen. Unlike if I hardcoded in.

Comment: the code as you posted it is incomplete. can you please post a minimal version that reproduces the issue, and tell us exactly where the List (not array) is empty?

Comment: updated so that the code makes more sense. pulled straight from MainActivity.

Comment: Call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the `for` loop in the `run()` method.

Comment: putting that line in gives an error `Cannot resolve symbol 'myAdapter'`. I think that myadapter is not a variable in that function.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that was in a separate method. You'll want to declare `private RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter;` at the top of your class, then remove `RecyclerViewAdapter` from the beginning of the `RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new ...` line in `onCreate()`.

Comment: applying everything you said, the program spits out this error; `Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: Oh, jeez, sorry, I'm really fumbling it tonight. You have to do one more step, 'cause you're handling the threading yourself. You'll need to put that `notifyDataSetChanged()` call in a `Runnable` and pass it to `runOnUiThread()`; e.g., `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() { myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); });`.

Comment: look at the original thread

Comment: When you mentioned it the first time, I applied that right after the for loop and then the error came up

Comment: wait did you mean I had to remove the `.start();`

Comment: Yeah I got it. I am pretty dumb so can you explain what you did.

Comment: No what you said worked. But I have confused on how and why

Comment: You're starting a separate `Thread` in your `getWebsite()` method, so it doesn't block the main thread. That means that `getWebsite()` returns immediately, and the rest of your `onCreate()` continues to run while that `Thread` is doing its thing at the same time. The `onCreate()` method gets done quicker, however, so by the time you get the data processed, the `RecyclerView` has already been set up, and you need to let it know that you've added new items to its dataset. The `runOnUiThread()` is necessary because that's just how handling `View`s works.

Comment: You can't touch them directly on your separate `Thread`, so you post that `Runnable` to the main thread to run there. Follow me?

Comment: Oh. I just lacked the understanding of the how the parts were moving. But thanks to your expertise, I was able to solve this problem. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a multi threading issue. You access the list from different threads, without synchronization, so expect any kind of issue. You could use a thread safe list, but honestly, I would consider to redesign with multi threading in mind. Best solution is, to access the list only from one thread.

Comment: That way of making a method is something from a tutorial online. Can't there be a way I can make the call within the main function or was making a new thread the only way to do so.

Comment: I mean, you start the thread before you populate the list. Then, the list is not thread safe and will have strange effects when written from two threads concurrently. Why don't you put these lines into the thread itself?